# How do I bring the console window back into the same Unity window?

Tags: unity, console

I have this issue where somehow I accidentally got the console window separated from the window that all unity things are n, so it floats around, blocking the unity screen behind it, as shown below:

[image: Broken Console Window]

And I don't know how to fix it. I tried right clicking the projects tab but the option to add the console window wasn't there. I also tried dragging around the console window back into place but that didn't work. Whenever I restart this still happens, and even new projects have this issue, ever since I accidentally dragged the window out from the unity window shown behind it in the image I showed. There has to be a simple fix to this.

Comment: When you dragged the window, did you do it by the "tab" part, or by the "window top" part?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The little tab-looking-thing that says "console" on it is what I accidentally dragged.

Comment: Yes. The little tab looking thing where it says "console".

Comment: Yeah, I dragged it by the "tab" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just click and drag the "Console" tab until it snaps to the place where you want it.

[image: Dragging Console panel]

If you have trouble, you can open the Window menu and select Layouts > Default (or another layout of your choice) to force all panels back into some standard arrangeement.

Comment: It doesn't snap back into place. I am using Unity 2018.3.0f2

Comment: But, fortunately, your Layouts suggestion worked! Thank you.

Comment: The snapping isn't a new feature - it's been there since before Unity versions were labelled in years. So if it's not working for you, there could be a problem with your installation, or some OS settings.